# Connect to multiple Firebase DB

Tags: firebase, flutter

My flutter app needs to connect to multiple firebase databases. the vision is that the user will start the application and will enter Firebase parameters and click "Connect".
I find the following source lines

```
FirebaseApp app;
  Future<FirebaseApp> FBDB() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
      name: "FB.AAA.com", // "package_name"
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
        googleAppID: "1:79046:android:2fb2895a41bde78da062d",
        // "mobilesdk_app_id"
        gcmSenderID: "???",
        //"project_number":
        apiKey: "AIzamVHoX0C_zimD3UhUITF4ml7Be4fsI",
        //  "api_key": [ { "current_key"
        projectID: "fb-b64d", //"project_id"
      ),
    );
  }
```

The Google Services file is (changed the data):

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "123",
    "firebase_url": "https://fb-b64d.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "fb-b64d",
    "storage_bucket": "fb-b64d.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:79046:android:2fb2895a41bde78da062d",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "FB.AAA.com"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "123-5555.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzamVHoX0C_zimD3UhUITF4ml7Be4fsI"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "793081656-5555.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

The result of the source code above is null (the object was not created) so my questions are:

1. Did I take the right parameters from the google Json file to the source code above? what should be in the gcmSenderID?
2. what is the next step? how should I receive the

   ```
   final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance
   ```

   In order to start query the DB?

Comment: I updated my question, due to your answer my question now is more focused (I hope)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a Firebase service for a specific `FirebaseApp` instance, you pass that app into the service's constructor or call a factory method.

For example:

```
FirebaseDatabase(app: this.app).reference();
```

For for auth:

```
FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app)
```